# Visual Studio 2015 post build run ps1 file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2015

i am trying to get a PowerShell .ps1 script "Deploy.ps1" to run after a successful build completes in my Visual Studio 2015 project.

previously I got this to work in Visual Studio 2019 by putting Deploy.ps1 inside my project, and adding this post-build command in the VS2019 project properties:

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted $(ProjectDir)Deploy.ps1
```

if I put the same Deploy.ps1 file inside my VS2015 project, and add the same post build step, my build fails every time with an error saying it exited with code 1:

[image]

```
1>------ Build started: Project: portdemo2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  portdemo2 -> C:\Users\320178017\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\portdemo2\portdemo2\bin\Debug\portdemo2.dll
1>  C:\Users\320178017\Documents\Visual : The term 'C:\Users\320178017\Documents\Visual' is not recognized as the name of 
1>  a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, 
1>  verify that the path is correct and try again.
1>  At line:1 char:1
1>  + C:\Users\320178017\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\portdemo2\portdemo2\D ...
1>  + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\320178017\Documents\Visual:String) [], CommandNotFoundExceptio 
1>     n
1>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
1>   
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4714,5): error MSB3073: The command "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted C:\Users\320178017\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\portdemo2\portdemo2\Deploy.ps1" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

it looks like it fails at the `Visual`  of "Visual Studio" in my path, like the space is messing it up. I've tried wrapping my script path within quotes inside VS2015 like so but with no change: `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted "$(ProjectDir)Deploy.ps1"`

Can anyone help me running a post-build ps1 file in Visual Studio 2015? Thanks

Comment: What's the error message after you add the quotes?

Comment: Try using single quotation marks.

Comment: Add -File parameter `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "$(ProjectDir)Deploy.ps1"`

Comment: or `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted "& '$(ProjectDir)Deploy.ps1'"` maybe might work also

Comment: single quotes works